# Swift Encodable Array of Objects

Tags: json, swift, encode

I am trying to render a Swift Encodable struct to the following JSON:

```
{
   "userID": 1000142,
   "emergencyContactData": {"contact": 
       [
           {"firstName": "John"}, 
           {"lastName": "Doe"},
           {"email": "john.doe567@gmail.com"}, 
           {"phone": "12345678901"}
       ]
   }
}
```

I tried the following:

```
struct UserEmergencyContactRequest: Encodable {
    var userID: String
    var ecData: EmergencyContactData
}

struct EmergencyContactData: Encodable {
    var contact: [[String: String]]
}
```

However, the individual String: String dictionary entries do not render to a JSON object (no curly braces).  How would I alter the [String: String] entry so that when I render it to a JSON structure, the individual String: String values would be enclosed in a set of JSON curly braces?

**Note**: No, I cannot alter the service to accept a better format, dealing with a legacy service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The structures are correct

I think the problem is in the way you are populating your structs (not shown in your question).

### The error

This is the wrong code that *I guess* you are using.

> Specifically the error is in the way you are populating the `dictionaries` value. Infact you are creating a an array with a single dictionary having all the values. Instead you should create an array of dictionaries where each dictionary has 1 single entry.

```
let dictionaries = [["firstName" : "John", "lastName": "Doe", "email": "john.doe567@gmail.com", "phone": "12345678901"]]
let ecData = EmergencyContactData(contact: dictionaries)
let elm = UserEmergencyContactRequest(userID: "userID", ecData: ecData)

if
    let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(elm),
    let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(string)
}


{"userID":"userID","ecData":{"contact":[{"email":"john.doe567@gmail.com","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","phone":"12345678901"}]}}
```

### The fix

As said above, let's try to put 1 single entry into each dictionary.

```
let dictionaries = [["firstName" : "John"], ["lastName": "Doe"], ["email": "john.doe567@gmail.com"], ["phone": "12345678901"]]

let ecData = EmergencyContactData(contact: dictionaries)
let elm = UserEmergencyContactRequest(userID: "userID", ecData: ecData)

if  let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(elm),
    let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(string)
}
```

Now we get the expected result.

```
{"userID":"userID","ecData":{"contact":[{"firstName":"John"},{"lastName":"Doe"},{"email":"john.doe567@gmail.com"},{"phone":"12345678901"}]}}
```